# Datastax java driver 3.0.0 Enumerated annotation not found

Tags: java, enums, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Hope I am reading the docs well:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/java-driver/reference/crudOperations.html.

> The Enumerated annotation
>
> If your class contains an enum type field, you use the Enumerated annotation.

I have a Java enum and I want to use the @Enumerated annotation, but I can't seem to find it in 3.0.0 version of the driver, it was present in 2.1.9.

```
$ find . -type f -name \*.jar|while read i; do echo ====== $i =====; jar -tf $i|grep Enumerated; done
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/2.1.4/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4-javadoc.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/2.1.4/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4-sources.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/2.1.4/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/2.1.5/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/2.1.7.1/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/2.1.9/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/3.0.0/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0-sources.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-core/3.0.0/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-dse/2.1.5/cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.5.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-extras/3.0.0/cassandra-driver-extras-3.0.0.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-mapping/2.1.4/cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.4-javadoc.jar =====
com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/class-use/Enumerated.html
com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Enumerated.html
====== ./cassandra-driver-mapping/2.1.4/cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.4-sources.jar =====
com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Enumerated.java
====== ./cassandra-driver-mapping/2.1.4/cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.4.jar =====
com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Enumerated.class
====== ./cassandra-driver-mapping/2.1.7.1/cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.7.1.jar =====
com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Enumerated.class
====== ./cassandra-driver-mapping/2.1.9/cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.9.jar =====
com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Enumerated.class
====== ./cassandra-driver-mapping/3.0.0/cassandra-driver-mapping-3.0.0-sources.jar =====
====== ./cassandra-driver-mapping/3.0.0/cassandra-driver-mapping-3.0.0.jar =====
```

Has this changed in the new release? If yes, the docs should probably be updated too.

It does seem to be gone from the sources: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.0/driver-mapping/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like support for @Enumerated has been removed. Now, enums support is provided by the codecs in drivers-extras. Check out these two tickets for addtional info: [JAVA-605](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-605) and [JAVA-846](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-846).

An [example](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/commit/99de43355315d26a7898ba1ff272dce45c19168b#diff-65fed7351e93083ce320a8816fdd839eR211) of what your enums code might look like is:

> [Use] `EnumOrdinalCodec` and `EnumNameCodec`:
>
> ```
>  java    
>  enum Foo {...}
>  enum Bar {...}
>
>  // register the appropriate codecs
>  CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE
>      .register(new EnumOrdinalCodec<Foo>(Foo.class))
>      .register(new EnumNameCodec<Bar>(Bar.class))
>
>  // the following mappings are handled out-of-the-box
>  @Table
>  public class MyPojo {
>      private Foo foo;
>      private List<Bar> bars;
>      ...
>  }
> ```

We are in the process of fixing the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, after posting the question I found the codecs, unfortunately I was in a hurry, got confused and quickly wrote my own codec instead of using EnumNameCodec...I'll switch to EnumNameCodec (I'm just doing a PoC, nothing production-critical, but better to use the official codec anyway).

Answer (score 0):

In quarkus I've done it next way.
Introduced separate bean and subscribed to event when app ready

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppLifecycleBeanCodecRegistration {

  @Inject
  CqlSession session;

  // to check db before start (CassandraClientStarter) - quarkus.cassandra.init.eager-init=true
  void onStart(@Observes @Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION - 10) StartupEvent ev) {
    TypeCodec<User.Role> myEnumCodec = new EnumNameCodec<>(User.Role.class);

    MutableCodecRegistry registry = (MutableCodecRegistry) session.getContext().getCodecRegistry();
    registry.register(myEnumCodec);
  }
}
```

and then dse java driver automatically mapped my enum to TEXT properly.